# How can I use for loop in HTML to display data in a table with format

Tags: html, django, html-table

So I'm a beginner and I'm using django and python. I created a table here and I want to display all data in a queryset. Plus I want to have 4 columns. So I want something like, for each four items in the queryset, create a  and display the 4 items, but it seems like I can only do one item in each loop.

My code looks like this, and it's dipslaying one each row right now.

[Code for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQTw.png)

Is it possible to do this in html?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column1</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><img src="{{user.img_url}}"></a></td>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.bookmarks.count}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sry probably my question wasn't clear, I want to have 4 users displayed in each row, not four attributes of one user. That's what I'm confusing about